# Calculating Decimal points of modulo operations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, cryptography

I am not too sure of the step that has occurred here (I found this form a cryptography book but I do not understand how he finds the second 9).

The function found in the  image is
$(2 \cdot 1)^{-1}(3 \cdot 5^2 + 2) = 2^{-1} \cdot 9 \equiv 9 \cdot 9 \equiv 13\,\mod\,17$

My calculations are that:
$(2 \cdot 1)^{-1}(3 \cdot 5^2 + 2) = 2^{-1} \cdot 9 = 4.5 \not\equiv 9 \cdot 9 \equiv 13\,\mod\,17$

[Equation from Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU74n.png)

Comment: What have decimal points got to do with this?

Comment: @badjohn confusing modular multiplicative inverse with reciprocal.

Comment: I was wondering whether the dot for multiplication was causing confusion.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, Alex; $4.5$ is not an element of integers modulo $17$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How he finds the second $9$:

$2^{-1}\equiv9\pmod{17}$ because $9\cdot2=18\equiv1\pmod{17}$

Comment: element times its inverse should be the multiplicative identity

Answer (score 1):

The ${^{-1}}$ is for modular multiplicative inverse, not reciprocal. Even if you treat it that way: $$4+2^{-1}=4+{1\over 2}\equiv 4+{18\over 2}=4+9=13\pmod {17}$$ in this case.

Comment: This is a somewhat minor point, but the middle "=" really should be the equivalent symbol (i.e., "\equiv" in MathJax) instead as $4 + \frac{1}{2} \neq 4 + \frac{18}{2}$.

Comment: Hmmm.... this isn't wrong but I'm *really* wary of having students think of this as division and do such abuses.  $\frac a2\pmod n\equiv \frac {a\pmod n}2\equiv \frac {a+n\pmod n}2\equiv \frac {a+n}2\pmod n$ is a *real* abuse of concept even if its can be verified to give  a correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, because the use of linear polynomials isn't.

Comment: Also two things are equal if they are congruent in all modulo.

Answer (score 1):

In modulo arithimetic then expression $(2^{-1})$ does not mean $0.5$ which is completely out of the purview of modular arithmetic (which is about equivalence classes of *integers*).

Instead $(2^{-1})$ refers to the the solution to  $2x \equiv 1\pmod n$

And $2x \equiv 1 \pmod {17}\iff x \equiv 9 \pmod {17}$[1]

So $2^{-1}\equiv 9 \pmod {17}$.

======

[1]  $2x \equiv 1 \pmod {17} \implies \exists k\in \mathbb Z$ so that $2x = 1 + 17k$ so $2|1+17k$ but $2\not \mid 1$ so $2\not \mid 17k$ so $k$ is odd.  If $k = 2m + 1$ then $2x = 1 + (2m+1)17 = 18 + 34m$ which means $x = 9 + 17m$ or $x \equiv 9 \pmod {17}$ is the only solution ($\pmod {17}$).